# How to tell if a person has modified any content on a SharePoint site programmatically?

Tags: powershell, spweb

We need to find out if a disgrunted employee has modified any content on any number of many SharePoint sites we have.  Aside from how we are currently reviewing lists by modified date manually (fortunately he was only with us and only had access a short time), can this be sped up programmatically?

I was looking to find out if there was a non-invasive way to do this through a Powershell script or other means that could poll every list, document library, etc. for a given "Modified By" (and potentially also a given Modified date, to speed up the results). I don't have access to the servers, themselves, to load managed code - they're ran by a separate team.

Here is my attempt at running a Powershell script I got from another site (it was riddled with errors I've been cleaning up), but it is at the point it should be pulling up webs for the given URL I supply, and it is not returning anything (I have admin access on the given site, given via AD group added to the Owners group on the site).  Problem is on `$webs = Get-SPWeb $URL` where it just gives 0 when I write out the `.count`:

```
param
(
    [string] $URL,
    [string] $InputWriteToFile,
    [bool] $WriteToFile = $false
)

Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#Counter variables
$webcount = 0
$listcount = 0

$URL = Read-Host "Site to check: "
$InputWriteToFile = Read-Host "Export to file? (Y/N) "

if ($InputWriteToFile -eq "Y" -OR $InputWriteToFile -eq "y")
{
    $WriteToFile = $true
}
else
{
    $WriteToFile = $false
}

if($WriteToFile -eq $true)
{
    $outputPath = Read-Host "Output path (e.g. C:\directory\filename.txt)"
}
if(!$URL)
{
    #Grab all webs
    #$webs = (Get-SPSite -limit all | Get-SPWeb -Limit all -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
#}
#else
#{
    $webs = Get-SPWeb $URL
}

Write-Host $webs.count
if($webs.count -ge 1 -AND $webs.count -ne $null)
{
    foreach($web in $webs)
    {
        #Grab all lists in the current web
        $lists = $web.Lists   
        Write-Host "Website"$web.url -ForegroundColor Green 
        if($WriteToFile -eq $true){Add-Content -Path $outputPath -Value "Website $($web.url)"}
        foreach($list in $lists)
        {
            $listcount +=1  
            Write-Host " – "$list.Title          
            if($WriteToFile -eq $true){Add-Content -Path $outputPath -Value " – $($list.Title)"}
        }
        $webcount +=1
        $web.Dispose()
    }
    #Show total counter for checked webs & lists
    Write-Host "Amount of webs checked:"$webcount
    Write-Host "Amount of lists:"$listcount
}
else
{
   Write-Host "No webs retrieved, please check your permissions" -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor Black
}
```

Comment: Are you running this as a member for the Farm Admins group?

Comment: No - should I have to?  Is there a way around that, if I do?

Comment: Changed the `$webs` line to `$webs = (Get-SPSite 'https://hostname.domain.com' | Get-SPWeb -Limit All)` and it said `Get-SPSite : Cannot find an SPSite object with Id or Url:  https://hostname.domain.com` (site name changed here for privacy). Also tried the fix of adding my account to the ShellAdmin using http://bramnuyts.be/en/2011/06/08/get-spweb-cannot-find-an-spweb-object-with-id-or-url/ but it didn't recognize the site, again:  `Get-SPContentDatabase : Cannot find an SPSite object with Id or Url:  https://hostname.domain.com`.